# Sometimes yes and sometimes not JSON error: "No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String'"

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, .net, json

Here's my code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, string> responseVals = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);
```

When `response` is

```
{
  "status": 21007
}
```

it works.

When `response` is

```
{
  "receipt": {
    "receipt_type": "ProductionSandbox",
    "adam_id": 0,
    "app_item_id": 0,
    "bundle_id": "...",
    "application_version": "1.0",
    "download_id": 0,
    "version_external_identifier": 0,
    "receipt_creation_date": "...",
    "receipt_creation_date_ms": "...",
    "receipt_creation_date_pst": "...",
    "request_date": "...",
    "request_date_ms": "...",
    "request_date_pst": "...",
    "original_purchase_date": "...",
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "...",
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "...",
    "original_application_version": "1.0",
    "in_app": [
      {
        "quantity": "1",
        "product_id": "...",
        "transaction_id": "...",
        "original_transaction_id": "...",
        "purchase_date": "...",
        "purchase_date_ms": "...",
        "purchase_date_pst": "...",
        "original_purchase_date": "...",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "..",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "...",
        "is_trial_period": "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 0,
  "environment": "Sandbox"
}
```

I get an error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String'

Why the difference?

This is in a web service (Asp.net) verifying an iOS in app purchase (in sandbox). Perhaps this matters.

Comment: The 2nd response doesn't look like it would deserialise into a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the difference?

> Your first example is working because you are passing primitive data
>   to deserialize into `Dictionary<string, string>`, but in second example you are trying to convert custom
>   object i.e `receipt` to string which is not prossible

---

If you want to deserialize specific property then you can convert this json string to `JObject` and then use that property to get the value

```
    string json = @"{
      status: '20122',
      OS: [
        'Windows',
        'macintosh'
      ]
    }";

    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
    Console.WriteLine(obj["status"]);  //20122
```

[.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8XeGqP)

Comment: Can't it just put that whole object into a string?

Comment: @Neil I know. But what if I don't need to deserialize it completely. I just need one of the other values.

Comment: Write your own `JsonConvert` class, to handle it.  Or don't deserialise the json, interpret the string manually.  Or write json classes to handle the actual data (it's very easy, built into VS2019 Edit/Paste Special/Paste as JSON classes).

Comment: @ispiro, as per your last comment, to get specific value from complete json string, you can convert it to `JObject` and then access the value

Answer (score 1):

One of the major advantages of Json decoders, is that they generally ignore any fields that are present in the json, but not in the deserialised class.

If you just want status and ignore all the rest, you can do this:

```
public  class Data
{
    public string Status {get;set;}
}

public void A()
{
    Data data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second response will not be deserialized into a dictionary, you can try desirialize it to object.

```
object objClass = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(response);
```

or create your own object and deserialize to it.

You can use [from Json to classes](https://www.jsonutils.com/), it will generate classes based on your json structure.